# JavaScript Equality Operator

Tags: javascript

In javascript whats the difference between 
`undefined == variable` and `variable == undefined` are both of them same? and how different will it be if i do `undefined === variable` or `typeof variable == 'undefined'`?

Can someone help me out

Comment: All are the same. If you want to check if a variable has not been defined use "variable=== undefined". If you want to check if a variable contains data use "if (variable)". This is the same as "if (variable !== undefined && variable !== null)". You should always use === instead of ==. With == you are implicitly doing a type conversion, e.g. 1 == "1" = true, 1 === "1" = false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `undefined` to test for an undefined variable, use the typeof operator instead!

`undefined` isn't a javascript keyword, it's just a variable name. If someone writes `var undefined = true` globally anywhere into the code, all your comparisons will act unexpected.

You should consider using something like JSLINT or JSHINT to avoid these type of errors in your javascript code.

Apart from that, I would always write the compared parameter first, as that's the way I read it.
That is why `If the variable foo is undefined than` should be written as `if (typeof foo === "undefined")`

I don't remember the name for this pattern, but I'm quite sure there is one :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in meaning when it comes to different order of parts you mentioned.

`===` is strict comparison, `==` is not. For example `undefined == false` is true, but `undefined === false` is not. Checking the undefined type is similar to strict comparison in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`undefined == variable` and `variable == undefined` are the same.

but i recomment `undefined == variable` to prevent strange behalves if you miss a `=` (`variable = undefined`).

`undefined === variable` and `typeof variable == 'undefined'` should also be the same.

Comment: I disagree with your recommendation. Order is okay, but in some cases it is possible to override original value of `undefined` (although in newer ES5 makes this variable read-only).

Comment: Yep. There's a recommendation of writing code this way, but `undefined` could be rewritten in js, hence it doesn't work in this case. And overwriting `undefined` would lead to even more strange behavior. I prefer the option with `typeof`.